# Problems with screen size on iPhoneX using SpriteKit

Tags: swift, iphone, sprite-kit

While following a Sprite Kit tutorial I noticed that using UIScreen.main.bounds to get the extents of the screen that it worked on most iPhone sizes apart from iPhoneX and 11. I wrote a quick test shown below where I move the anchor point to CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) and then place 3 labels 20, 40 and 60 points from the left edge. This works normally except on iPhoneX where the numbers shifted to the left. What am I doing wrong?

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds


var testLabel1: SKLabelNode!
var testLabel2: SKLabelNode!
var testLabel3: SKLabelNode!



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    print (screenSize)


    anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    testLabel1 = SKLabelNode(text: "1")
    testLabel1.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.left
    testLabel1 = initialiseLabel(label: testLabel1, position: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 50))
    testLabel2 = SKLabelNode(text: "2")
    testLabel2.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.left
    testLabel2 = initialiseLabel(label: testLabel2, position: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 50))
    testLabel3 = SKLabelNode(text: "3")
    testLabel3.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.left
    testLabel3 = initialiseLabel(label: testLabel3, position: CGPoint(x: 60, y: 50))
    self.addChild(testLabel1)
    self.addChild(testLabel2)
    self.addChild(testLabel3)

}

func initialiseLabel(label: SKLabelNode, position: CGPoint) -> SKLabelNode{
    label.position = position
    label.fontSize = 36
    label.fontName = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
    label.fontColor = UIColor.white
    return label
}
```

Comment: Can you post either some images of the issues you're having on the newer iPhone screens, or some log output?

Comment: Your scene size and screen size are 2 different things.  In sprite kit, you do not need to worry about screen size.  You worry about what size you want to work in, how it will look on various aspect ratios, and how it will scale to meet the sizes of various devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on here is you are using the default scene size, which would be 768x1366.

It is then scaling while preserving the aspect ratio to fill up the entire screen of the phones.

768x1366 is a 9:16 ratio.

X and on devices no longer conform to 9:16.  They are in fact, now thinner(wider depending on your orientation)

What this means is you are going to lose information on the left and right side in portrait mode because you are drawing to a much fatter box, and that extra content just can't be drawn on the screen.

To fix this, you are going to need to determine how you plan on handling all aspect ratios.

they are 3:4, 9:16, 6:13, 512x683,139x199, and 207x448 (oy, apple really stopped caring)

Basically, you should just start accounting for any aspect ratio.

I personally recommend that you use a square scene to design your game environment,  this way you have all your bases covered.

You then could use UIKit for any static information that needs to mount to certain locations on the screen, and all of this information does not end up bogging down your sprite kit engine.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by, "_I personally recommend that you use a square scene to design your game environment_"? That is, if you had a single-screen game, how do you present the same aspect ratio on all sizes? Is there an easy way to letterbox on "wider" phones? Or is the "box" method simply saying you're going to have to scroll to see it all, no matter the ratio? **EDIT:** [This](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121317) might be the answer?

Comment: You use the box so that you can handle any aspect ratio thrown at you a lot easier.  You do not send the same aspect ratio to all devices, instead you allow people to see a different amount of content.  A wider aspect ratio will see more more content on the sides, while a taller aspect ratio will see more content on top and bottom.