# UIScreen.main.bounds returning incorrect size

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

UIScreen.main.bounds.width and UIScreen.main.bounds.height are both wrong. It's returning 414x736 but it should be about 360x640.
Device: iPhone 8 Plus.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/q/59555848/1187415 ?

Comment: 414 x 736 is correct. That’s what your software needs to use to do any calculations.

Comment: @AlbertUI explained it, iPhone plus models downsample by 1.15. I'm using SpriteKit and I think it skips this step, so I need to use 360x640 in calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone `[Any]` Plus native rendering resolutions are downsampled by ÷1.15 because screens didn't have enough pixels to show @3x until iPhone X arrived.

Screen resolution is 360x640 physical points but screen rendering is 414x736 software points. That only happens on `Plus` models.

```
414 ÷ 1.15 = 360
736 ÷ 1.15 = 640
```

Check out this: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when you call the function.

You have to call this after View Appear fully.

```
override func viewDidLoad() { // Or viewDidAppear()
{
    let frame = self.view.bounds; // or UIScreen.main.bounds also works
}
```

You will get different value if you call the function on viewWillAppear.

Comment: Did you try self.view.bounds?

Comment: yes, it was also wrong

Comment: What is your iphone type?
Because I can't find any iphone which has 360*640.

Comment: https://devhints.io/resolutions

Please check here for iphone size.

Comment: its an iPhone 8 Plus
resolution is 1920x1080
when I place a sprite the corner seems to be about 360pt x and 640pt y

Comment: Oh, then, 414x736 is right.

Comment: when I place a sprite in the corner seems to be at about 360pt x and 640pt y. I am using SpriteKit

Comment: UIScreen.main.bounds returns size as pixel not pt, You have to convert pixel to pt by your code (possibly using extension)

Comment: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds returns size as pixel.
414x736 isn't pixels